# Python: How to print position and value of list element?

Tags: python

I have a list which includes <s>infinite</s> an unknown number of elements (I don't have control on the length of the list or the type of values)

```
a = [x, y, z ...]
```

where x = 1, y = 9, z = 'Hello' ...

And I would like to loop over list "a" and print all the elements' names and values.
I hope if I can implement something like that:

```
for i in a:
    print i $i
```

I would like to have output as:

```
x 1
y 9
z Hello
```

Comment: How can you have a list of infinite number of elements?

Comment: Maybe he means a generator?

Comment: @Smac89 be careful, this may be Chuck Norris.

Comment: Lists don't keep references to variables laying around like that. When you create a list with a set of variables, the list only holds the object the variables pointed to: `x=1;y=2;print [x,y]` gives you `[1, 2]` - not the original variable names. If you want to keep an association between variable names and their values, use a dict.

Comment: Guys why so many downvotes? This is clearly a beginner asking a reasonable question. He/she seems to be a bit lost about the length of the list, that's all.

Comment: @tdelaney I think he just wants to print it ... (as some kind of heuristic for how long the infinite set has been running perhaps?) (edit: ahh maybe I misunderstood the original OP's question...)

Comment: @Monster you should probably clarify what you mean by "infinite number of elements" and if the elements inside the list are variables, strings, floats or what.

Comment: Thanks guys ... sorry if my question wasn't clear. Yes, I meant infinite as not knowing the length of the list and I don't have control on the type of values of each element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import cycle # an infinite repeating set
my_infinite = cycle(["a","b","c"])
a=1,b=4,c=99
for val in my_infinite:
    print val, globals()[val]
```

maybe ... its aweful and hackey but it might work

Comment: Using enumerate is interesting, but my variables can have different values. x=1, y=4, z=999, ... So I need more general solution not to  put into account a specific order

Comment: yeah I misunderstood your question ... see tdelaney's comment in your question ... you really cannot do this  (see my edit for something that may work for you...)

Comment: Upvote for being patient with a newcomer even though the question was quite cryptic.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import string

for a, b in zip(string.ascii_lowercase, xrange(1, 27)):
    print a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dictionary:

```
a = {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

for i in a:
    print i, a[i]
```

Comment: this is almost guaranteed to not be the right answer ... since he explicitly says its an infinite list (no such thing... but im guessing he means a generator of some sort), which is not possible with a dictionary

Comment: The idea is that I don't want to place them in a dictionary. I don't want to rewrite the data as they change

Comment: Yes, sorry. my question wasn't very clear